# Images won't display horizontally

Tags: html, css

I tried using both inline and inline-block, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

http://jsbin.com/bixako/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion, the other answers are sort of hacky and do not address the real cause of this problem. The reason why this is happening is specifically related to using the html `<figure></figure>` tag which you've been putting your `<img />` tags inside of.

> The `<figure>` tag specifies self-contained content, like illustrations, diagrams, photos, code listings, etc.
>   **While the content of the  element is related to the main flow, its position is independent of the main flow**, and if removed it should not affect the flow of the document.
>   Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp

The `<figure>` tag is going to automatically displace the element's position independent of the main content flow, and this is why it only seems to move into flow by using CSS `float` or `position: absolute` because `float` and absolute position also displace an element's position from it's main position flow.

Eliminate the `<figure>` tags and you will once again be able to use `white-space: nowrap;`, `display: inline-block;` and all the regular content flow alignment tricks.

Comment: Here's proof: http://jsbin.com/bemobewina/edit?html,output All I did was remove the `<figure>` tags and add a minimum width to ul#imglist. voila!

Answer (score 0):

Set the #imglist li to be float:left and clear the #imglist to prevent any overlap.

I quickly edited your example here http://jsbin.com/jutalasuqi/edit?html,output

I shrank the images as the sizes didn't fit next to each other.

Comment: perhaps show us a snippet demonstrating?

Comment: Was already making one.. Updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Add below code and it will work:

```
#imglist li figure {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display: inline;
}
```

But still you need to fix the image size, li margin/padding issue to  make them beautiful/organize.

Thanks

Comment: This example doesn't work because it's not a margin / padding issue. Adding this code to your project will not produce any desired results.